Numerical Computation of the Gamma Function for large complex numbers
I'm looking for a method to numerically compute the Gamma function $Γ(z)$ for complex numbers of the form $$z= \frac{1}{2} + it,$$ particularly for large values of $t$.
Does anyone know of any representations or good approximations that would facilitate this computation?

does this help, it says use sympy to do the computation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54335790/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-gamma-function-in-python-for-large-complex-argument

See Numerical Recipes Lanczos Formula.

Lanczos Formula.
